# Как обрезать часть ImageView используя градусы угла?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Как обрезать часть ImageView используя градусы угла?

Пример: [image: Пример]

думаю можно сначала рисовать какой нибудь `<shape>` с определенным углом, и на него картинку с нужным режимом смешивания. Но пока не понял даже как сделать такой  `<shape>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение через `path.arcTo` и `canvas.clipPath`.

```
private val oval = RectF()
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

    val x = width/2f
    val y = height/2f
    val radius = width/2f

    oval.left = x - radius
    oval.top = y - radius
    oval.right = x + radius
    oval.bottom = y + radius

    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(x,y)
    path.arcTo(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle)
    path.close()

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Легко и просто - не получится. Надо кастомную вьюху делать, в которой рисовать сектор на Canvas.

Вот тут есть пара примеров кода по использованию `Canvas#drawArc()`: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-canvas-drawarc-method-a-visual-guide

В вашем случае - надо перекрыть ImageView кастомной вьюхой, размеры которой (ширина и высота, при условии что ImageView - кврадрат) должны быть равны диагонали ImageView. После этого в кастмной вьюхе нарисовать сектор с нужным углом - он перекроет ImageView именно так, как вы описываете.

Comment: Спасибо за `drawArc`! Он справляется, но он все же рисуется поверх картинки, а нужен был способ обрезать саму картинку, чтобы она стала прозрачной в обрезанном месте. Я уже нашел решение, используя `clipPath` нарисовав на нем тот же самый `Arc`